What happens to an interval when both endpoints are equal?
I couldn't find if this question had been asked before, but I was curious how an interval was defined if the endpoints were equal. I'm guessing that something like $[a, a) = a$, where $a$ is some constant in $R$, but what about $[a, a]$? Does $(a, a)$ exist?

The interval $[a,a]$ contains a single point, $a$.  Therefore, it is equal to the set $\{a\}$.
Personally, I would expect that $[a,a)$ should be interpreted as the empty set.  For instance, I would expect the property $b \notin [a,b)$ to hold, for all $a,b$, and then this implies that $[a,a)  = \emptyset$.  And I would expect the interval $[a,b)$ to be defined as follows:
$$[a,b) = \{x \mid a \le x \land x < b\},$$
which also implies that $[a,a)=\emptyset$.
But I recognize it is possible that others might have a different preference for the meaning of the notation $[a,b)$ and $[a,a)$.  If you prefer to deviate from the default I listed above, and the difference matters, then I suggest defining your notation before using it.
For similar reasons, $(a,a)$ is the empty set.

Wikipedia agrees with you about the empty set
